# Sorting Linked Lists - move nodes or swap data members?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a simple question.  I'm working on a C++ app that is a contact list app.  It stores names, addresses, numbers, ages, etc for multiple people.  I'm using stucts and linked lists (nodes).  I'm building the sort list function, to alphabetize the list.  I'm currently wondering if it's better to actually reorder the list by moving the structs as a whole or by swapping the data members inside each node.  At first, I considered moving the nodes, but now swapping the data members seems more safe, as I don't have to reorder the list.  At any rate, I don't know if either possesses any benefits over the other.

EDIT:  Here's the source code I'm working on.  Notice the sort function is incomplete.  Also, I'm still a novice programmer, so the coding will probably have a ton of issues, from a professional standpoint.  That, alongside the fact I'm not close to being done with it.  I'm only writing it to practice coding over my summer break between programming classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>//for functions in date function
#include <time.h> //for functions in date function
#include <sys/stat.h>//for mkdir functions
#include <unistd.h>//for usleep function
#include <ctype.h>//for toupper function in swap function

using namespace std;

struct PersonInfo
{
    char FirstName[20];
    char LastName[20];
    char Address[40];
    char PhoneNumber[20];

    int Age;

    PersonInfo *Link;
};

bool EmptyFileChecker(ifstream &FI, const char *P);
void AddPeopleToList(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer);
void RebuildOldList(ifstream &FI, PersonInfo *&HeadPointer, const char *P);
void DisplayList(PersonInfo *HeadPointer);
void SaveSettings(ofstream &FO, const PersonInfo *HeadPointer, const char *P);
void DisplayMenu(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer, const char *P, ifstream &FileIn, ofstream &FileOut);
void SortContacts(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer);
bool NamesInOrder(const char LastName1[], const char LastName2[]);
string Date();

//Delete Contact
//ENCRYPT LIST?

//Check for memory leaks in code and destructor?
//Return something - noun-like
//void adjective - like

int main()
{
    PersonInfo *HeadPointer;

    const char *Path = "/Users/josephlyons/Library/Application Support/The Lyons' Den Labs/TheLyons'DenContactInformation.txt";//code variable for username

    ifstream FileIn;
    ofstream FileOut;

    mkdir("/Users/josephlyons/Library/Application Support/The Lyons' Den Labs", ACCESSPERMS);//MODE??

    if (!EmptyFileChecker(FileIn, Path))
        AddPeopleToList(HeadPointer);

    else
        RebuildOldList(FileIn, HeadPointer, Path);

    DisplayMenu(HeadPointer, Path, FileIn, FileOut);

    //SortContacts(HeadPointer);

    SaveSettings(FileOut, HeadPointer, Path);
}

void DisplayMenu(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer, const char *P, ifstream &FileIn, ofstream &FileOut)
{
    short int MenuChoice;

    do
    {
        cout << "(1) Display Contact List\n";
        cout << "(2) Organize Contact List\n";//delete when done with program and automatically sort list before saving.
        cout << "(3) Add Contact/s\n";
        cout << "(4) Delete Contact/s\n";
        cout << "(5) Quit\n\n";

        cout << "Choice: ";
        cin >> MenuChoice;

        if (MenuChoice == 1)
            DisplayList(HeadPointer);

        else if (MenuChoice == 2)
            SortContacts(HeadPointer);

        else if (MenuChoice == 3)
            AddPeopleToList(HeadPointer);

        else if (MenuChoice == 4)
            cout << "choice 4";
    }
    while(MenuChoice != 5);
}

bool EmptyFileChecker(ifstream &FI, const char *P)//DONE
{
    FI.open(P);

    if (FI.fail())
        return false;

    else if (FI.eof())//return 0 if file doesnt exist or if file is empty
        return false;

    else
        return true;
}

void AddPeopleToList(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer)
{
    PersonInfo *CurrentPosition;

    char UserChoice;

    do
    {
        CurrentPosition = new PersonInfo;

        if (CurrentPosition == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Not enough memmory to make new contact.";
            return;
        }

        cout << "\nEnter First Name:   ";
        cin >> CurrentPosition->FirstName;
        CurrentPosition->FirstName[0] = toupper(CurrentPosition->FirstName[0]);//automatically capitalize first name

        cout << "Enter Last Name:    ";
        cin >> CurrentPosition->LastName;
        CurrentPosition->LastName[0] = toupper(CurrentPosition->LastName[0]);//automatically capitalize last name

        cin.ignore();//flushes a single newline left in input buffer from previous cin >>
        cout << "Enter Adress:       ";
        cin.getline(CurrentPosition->Address, 40);//using cin.get() to allow for spaces in address

        cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
        cin.getline (CurrentPosition->PhoneNumber, 20);//using cin.get() to allow for spaces in number

        cout << "Enter Age:          ";
        cin >> CurrentPosition->Age;

        cout << "\nAdd another contact? Y/N: ";
        cin >> UserChoice;

        cout << "\n";

        CurrentPosition->Link = HeadPointer;

        HeadPointer = CurrentPosition;
    }
    while (UserChoice == 'y' || UserChoice == 'Y');

    SortContacts(HeadPointer);
}

void RebuildOldList(ifstream &FI, PersonInfo *&HeadPointer, const char *P)
{
    PersonInfo *TemporaryPersonPointer;
    char EndOfListChecker = 1;//initialized at a not 0 to allow entrance into loop

    while (EndOfListChecker != 0)
    {
        TemporaryPersonPointer = new PersonInfo;

        if (TemporaryPersonPointer == NULL)
            cout << "Not enough memory to generate the full list";

        FI >> TemporaryPersonPointer->FirstName;
        FI >> TemporaryPersonPointer->LastName;

        FI.ignore();//flushes a single newline from input
        FI.getline(TemporaryPersonPointer->Address, 40);

        FI.ignore();
        FI.getline(TemporaryPersonPointer->PhoneNumber, 20);

        FI >> TemporaryPersonPointer->Age;

        TemporaryPersonPointer->Link = HeadPointer;

        HeadPointer = TemporaryPersonPointer;

        FI.get(EndOfListChecker);

        while (EndOfListChecker == '\n')
        {
            FI.get(EndOfListChecker);
        }

        if (EndOfListChecker != 0)
            FI.putback(EndOfListChecker);
    }
}

void DisplayList(PersonInfo *HeadPointer)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "\nFirst Name:   ";
        cout << HeadPointer->FirstName << endl;

        cout << "Last Name:    ";
        cout << HeadPointer->LastName << endl;

        cout << "Adress:       ";
        cout << HeadPointer->Address << endl;

        cout << "Phone Number: ";
        cout << HeadPointer->PhoneNumber << endl;

        cout << "Age:          ";
        cout << HeadPointer->Age;

        cout << "\n\n";

        HeadPointer = HeadPointer->Link;

        usleep(75000);
    }
    while (HeadPointer != NULL);

    cout << "Press enter to go to main menu: ";

    cin.ignore(2);

    cout << "\n";
}

void SaveSettings(ofstream &FO, const PersonInfo *HeadPointer, const char *P)
{
    FO.open(P);

    if (FO.fail())
        cout << "Couldn't Open File\n";

    while (HeadPointer != NULL)
    {
        FO << HeadPointer->FirstName   << endl;
        FO << HeadPointer->LastName    << endl;
        FO << HeadPointer->Address     << endl;
        FO << HeadPointer->PhoneNumber << endl;
        FO << HeadPointer->Age         << endl << endl;

        HeadPointer = HeadPointer->Link;
    }

    FO << (char) 0 << endl;

    FO << "Date of Settings: " << Date() << endl;

    FO.close();
}

void SortContacts(PersonInfo *&HeadPointer)
{
    PersonInfo *MovingPointer1;//used to "crawl" down list
    PersonInfo *MovingPointer2;//used to "crawl" down list
    PersonInfo *StaticPointer;//always points at first node to give HeadPointer a way to link back to the list at end
    PersonInfo *TemporaryPointer;//holds a node during a swap

    bool ZeroSwapsOccured = false;//initialized at false to allow entrance into loop once

    MovingPointer1 = StaticPointer = HeadPointer;//set all to point at first node

    MovingPointer2 = HeadPointer->Link;

    while (ZeroSwapsOccured == false)
    {
        ZeroSwapsOccured = true;

        while (MovingPointer2->Link != NULL)
        {
            if (!NamesInOrder(MovingPointer1->LastName, MovingPointer2->LastName))
            {
                ZeroSwapsOccured = false;

                //Temp = MP1
                //MP1  = MP2
                //MP2  = TEMP

                MovingPointer1->Link = MovingPointer2->Link;
                MovingPointer2->Link = MovingPointer1;
                HeadPointer->Link = MovingPointer2;
            }
        }
    }

    HeadPointer = StaticPointer;//link HeadPointer back to list after sort
}

bool NamesInOrder(const char LastName1[], const char LastName2[])
{
    for (int i = 0; LastName1[i] || LastName2[i]; ++i)//go until you get to the end of the larger name
    {
        if(toupper(LastName1[i]) < toupper(LastName2[i]))
           return true;

        if(toupper(LastName1[i]) > toupper(LastName2[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;//this will only be used if same last name

    //build in fucntionality to then go to first name after last name, if both last names are the same
}

string Date()//not my code here - just modified it to read easier
{
    char Time[50];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(Time, 50, "%b, %d, %Y", localtime(&now)); //short month name
    return string(Time);
}
```

Comment: if node data size is larger, that time its better to swap node's position rather then swap node's data(swapping data will be bad choice)

Comment: Also you're not moving the structs/nodes anywhere, you're changing what `next` points to.

Comment: @JonnyHenly you are correct, I used a poor choice of words.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal there's 3 char arrays, with sizes 20, 20, and 40.  An in array size 15, and another int.  So, it's not large, but not small.  I assume you suggest not using the data swap method, as creating a temporary node for the swap will use more memory?

Comment: Am just curious to know reason/advantage of using `Linked List` in your app.

Comment: @joe_04_04 I thought , you are using a structure to hold all the properties like name , addresses, ages etc... If that's not the case, swapping data would be fine.

Comment: @sameerkn iguess I could've used an array of structs instead of linked list, but I would have to dynamically allocate the array to hold the structs, as I don't know how many the user will fill up.  Also, I'm still a novice.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal yes, I am using a structure to hold it all.  Sorry for the vagueness, I will post the code when I get home.

Comment: @joe_04_04 no need to dynamically allocate the array to hold the structs, that's what a `vector` is meant to be used for.

Comment: @JonnyHenly, I've only completed 2 C++ classes, that answer is past my scope of knowledge :D, I will dig into vectors though on my own, since you mentioned it.

Comment: I added the code in the original post.

Comment: @joe_04_04: As per your comments, just a suggestion to you to invest some time and learn to use correct data structure depending upon the requirements. For example: as @Jonny Henly, suggested `vector` would be better in current scenario since there are less members in your `struct` and that to all of them are of static nature(means they have fixed memory allocated to them at compile time itself).

Comment: Thanks @sameerkn, I haven't learned about vectors in any of my comp science classes, but I'll do some studying on it now.

Comment: Yes it is better here to use vectors. As I answered below the good way to sort a linked list is to use a merge sort algorithm and not a bubble sort algorithm. You must learn the two (vectors and linked lists) well because every one has it's pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First -** You're reordering the list in both cases.

**Second -** 
Swapping two nodes usually takes five operations:

1. Change the node one back from the first node to point to the second node.
2. Change the node one back from the second node to point to the first node.
3. Store the first node's `next` pointer in a temporary pointer.
4. Change the first node's `next` pointer to the second node's `next` pointer.
5. Change the second node's `next` pointer to the temporary pointer.

Swapping two variables takes at least three operations:

1. Store the first variable in a temporary variable.
2. Change the first variable to the second variable.
3. Change the second variable to the first variable.

But now multiply that by the number of struct members.

The struct should have at least 2 data members - a pointer and a payload - so off the bat you're looking at, at least, 6 operations. Which will increase by 3 for each member in the struct. So you're better off just swapping the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

No memory should be moving. The nodes in a linked list are not ordered in memory but only in relation to each-other via  pointer(s) to the next/previous nodes in the list. your operation can be done with only a few pointer assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the data is more costly and complex. For example, to swap the data, you will need to swap the name, address, numbers, ages etc.

On the other hand, swapping the node means just swapping two memory location address inside your list. So, swapping the nodes is highly preferable.

Secondly, if you add more metaData fields to your node, you won't have to change the sort code to swap the newly added data field.

Answer (score 1):

If node data size is larger, that time it's better to swap node's position rather than swap node's data (swapping data will be bad choice).

Reasons of choosing moving the pointer implementation over swapping the data:

1. Let's suppose you want to add a new field to your contact list after some time. If you swap data, you will have to change your code every time you make changes to your contact list field.
2. As fields in contact list increase, overhead for swapping the data will grow.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a linked list that you want to sort. To do it correctly and efficiently you have to use the correct sorting algorithm which in this case is the Merge Sort. For sure you should not swap the nodes' data.

Check this link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/